# Mule choice node expression based on Header properties

Tags: mule, expression

how to route a message in mule using the choice node, based on the header properties in a message?

my message has two headers: prop1 and prop2.

when I try to route using this expression:

```
    <when expression="INBOUND:prop1=abc evaluator="header">
```

it works.

But when i try this:

```
    <when expression="INBOUND:prop1=abc and prop2=123" evaluator="headers">
```

it does not work. I mean, it goes to the "otherwise" flow even though i set the header properties correctly in the message.

any ideas will be appreciated a lot!

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Mule 3.3.x and both properties being strings:

```
<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.?prop1 == 'abc' and message.inboundProperties.?prop2 == '123']">
```

Note this is null-safe, ie `prop1` and `prop2` are not required to be there.

Comment: do you know if this is Mule 3.2.x compatible? I am running 3.2.1

Comment: Nope, this won't run on 3.2.x. Use the Groovy solution from @genjosanzo above on 3.2.x or upgrade to 3.3.x and use the MEL expression I suggested, which is the new unified expression language in Mule.

Comment: Refer to this: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-expression-language-reference#literals

Answer (score 1):

The header evaluator is not designed to deal with complex expression (i.e. it does not support logical operators)

From your sintax I assume you are using mule with version < 3.3.0 so the example based on [MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Expression+Language) won't probably fit your needs, although you should take this approach as soon as you'd upgrade.

In older mule version the best approach might be using the groovy expression evaluator and the when condition would look like the following

```
<when expression="#[groovy:message.getInboundProperty('prop1') == 'abc' && message.getInboundProperty('prop2') == '123']">
```